# Time and frequency extremes

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravitational-waves, cosmic-rays, proton-decay, positronium

I wonder if there exists a table of which physical events have the shortest time scale (like matter/antimatter annihilation) and which have the longest (like proton decay). The same question applies to the lowest (like maybe infrasound) and greatest frequency (like cosmic radiation) of wawes that describe some physical phenomenom.
I would expect any such table to show specific numbers or at least a range of numbers.

Comment: The question is ill-defined. Published proton decay limits will improve as experiments improve, they aren't actual physical timescales. Similarly cosmic ray energy limits or simply given by the size of our current detectors and possibly by our particular location in the universe. None of these have anything to do with fundamental physics.

Comment: This IS a valid question of physics, to which the answer is that there is no lower bound and upper bound (to some level of approximation, e.g., at some point the total energy in Univers probably set some bounds).  May the downvoters be a little less nasty in this forum ?

Comment: Maybe CuriousOne can tell me how long time it takes for an electron to jump from one orbit to another in a hydrogen atom or what is the angular frequency of the electrons +/- spin. I hope the questions are specific enough and has something to do with fundamental physics.

Comment: @Jens: here is a detailed calculation for the 21 cm emission line of neutral hydrogen atoms; it explains the origin of this emission, the frequency, and the half-life of the excited state: 11 million years. One typically does this as an excercise in a second course on quantum mechanics:  http://www.cv.nrao.edu/course/astr534/HILine.html

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the electromagnetic spectrum:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum

And particle decay rates:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_decay

and follow the references.